Network profile activity is showing auto-deleted duplicate auto-comments
My network profile shows comments that get automatically posted and immediately auto-deleted when I cast close votes with a dupe-hammer. And not just recent ones either. It goes all the way back to the fifth (last) page- almost two weeks ago.
I don't think such comments should get auto-posted at all if I'm dupe-hammering, but that's another matter.
I doubt this is related to Network profile activity is showing deleted comments.

Sometimes or always?

@W.O. it doesn't vary on page refreshes. I don't know if it occurs for all such comments. I could check, but I'm too lazy. I see enough that I'm going to assume for all of them.

It's late and I'm sleep-deprived, but does this post report the same issue?

@Spevacus yep. too bad it didn't show up when I searched with is:q [network-profile][deleted-comments]. also, (directed at nobody), why do I get a prompt to accept a community member dup-target-suggestion when I cast the first close vote on my question? it should just close.

@Glorfindel test successful.
